# How Do I Create Packet Headers?

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, networking, packet

basically I'm sending and receiving both images, strings and files over a client/server connection. I can easily use a protocol for string commands but I cannot distinguish between the incoming data [if data is image or whatever and then follow onward instructions].

So how do I make a packet using Dim buffer as byte() ?

Comment: Why couldn't you first send a control character? 1=text, 2=image etc... then you'll know what data you're receiving and you can act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to take a wild guess at what you are trying to do. If you are using a TCPListener to handle an incoming HTTP connection you could respond like so:

```
    Private Sub ServePNG()

        Dim stream As NetworkStream = mytcpclient.GetStream

        Dim Content As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("image.png")

        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        sb.Append("HTTP/1.0 200 OK" + ControlChars.CrLf)
        sb.Append("Content-Type: image/png" + ControlChars.CrLf)
        sb.Append("Content-Length: " + Content.Length.ToString + ControlChars.CrLf)
        sb.Append(ControlChars.CrLf)

        Dim Header() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString)
        stream.Write(Header, 0, Header.Length)
        stream.Write(Content, 0, Content.Length)

        client.Close()

    End Sub
```

I'm getting the byte array straight out of image.png

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new class which can contain an `Header Property` then  you can serialize that class then convert it to a byte array

Example:

```
Serializable()
    Public class Packet
    dim _header as packetHeader
    dim _data as byte()
    Public Property Header as packetHeader
    Get
    Return _Header
    End Get
    Set (byval value as packetHeader)
    _header = value
    End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Data as Object
    Get
    Return _Header
    End Get
    Set (byval value as Object)
    _data = value
    End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(Byval header as packetHeader, Byval data as Object)
    _header = header
    _data = data
    End Sub
    Public Shared Function Serialize(myPacket as Packet) as Byte()
    Dim fs as New MemoryStream
    Dim formatter as New BinaryFormatter
    formatter.Serialize(fs, myPacket)
    Return fs.ToArray
    End Function
    Public Shared Function Deserialize(strm() as Byte) as Packet
    Dim fs as New MemoryStream(strm)
    Dim formatter as New BinaryFormatter
    Return DirectCast(formatter.Deserialize(fs),Packet)
    End Function
    End Class
    'Example of use
    Public Enum packetHeader as Integer
    Text = 0
    Image = 1
    'etc
    End Enum
    'Inside button click event (sending the packet)
    Dim bitmap as new Bitmap("C:/example.png")
    Dim data as Object =  bitmap
    Dim myPacket as new Packet(packetHeader.Image, data)
    dim buffer() as byte = Packet.Serialize(myPacket)
    'to deserialize the packet and check the header
    Dim buffer() as byte = stream.Read
    Dim myPacket as Packet = Packet.Deserialize(buffer)
    Select myPacket.Header
    Case packetHeader.Image
    Dim image as Bitmap
    image = DirectCast(myPacket.Data, Bitmap)
    Case packetHeader.Text
    Dim str as String
    str = DirectCast(myPacket.Data, String)
    End Select
    'do your proccess inside the Select statement
```

Comment: sorry for bad formmating... im just new here >.<